# path to image works in CDN but not in .css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cdn

I don't get it. How does it works with CDN and not when I copy the CSS down to a local .CSS and reference it through BundleConfig.cs in MVC? 
I don't even know where to find the image.

Works CDN: (Gives up/down arrow in datatable header)

```
@Styles.Render("http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css")
```

Doesn't work: .CSS

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/dataTablesBootstrap").Include(
            "~/Content/dataTables-bootstrap.css"
            ));
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dataTablesBootstrap")
```

Error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/WebConsole53/images/sort_both.png"
```

Comment: The images urls are in the css file (background: url('../images/sort_asc_disabled.png'))
 http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

Comment: So if you go to this URL you will find the image: http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_desc_disabled.png

Comment: So if they are not located at my place, I should download those 5 images, and change the reference in the .css to those files yes?

Comment: I suggest you download the ZIP from here: http://datatables.net/download/download. It contains the images under folder: media/images. And then copy this images to your images folder

Comment: You should make an answer instead this is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you download the ZIP from here: 
datatables.net/download/download.

Copy the CSS Files to your:

`/Content/` OR `styles`

And copy your Images to

```
/images/
```

And it should work. I don't think you have to change the Reference in the css files

IF

`/content/` and `/images/` folder are in the same Directory